# Uploading xml file by FTP with C# - File always empty

Tags: c#, xml, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file by FTP using C#. The file is created but always empty and size is 0.
What am I doing wrong here ?

A problem with my stream or a line missing ?

Connexion and creation is working well.

Thanks.

Code here:

```
        {           
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
            Stream ftpStream = null;           

            string strMsg = string.Empty;
            try
            {

                
                String uploadUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", "ftp://IPADDRESS", "myfile.xml");
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uploadUrl));
               
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                /
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                ftpRequest.Timeout = 2000000;               
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

                
                try
                {
                    byte[] fileContent = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
                    ftpRequest.ContentLength = fileContent.Length;
                    Stream requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();

                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                    strMsg = "File Upload Status: " + response.ToString();

                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
                   
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);` ? This is wasteful at best. In the worst case, if the file was created in a codepage different from the current account's locale it mangles the text. Open a stream on the file with eg `using var fileStream=File.OpenRead(path);` and copy its contents to the request stream with `Stream.CopyTo`. Use a `using` block or `using var` instead of closing the stream manually. Right now the stream is left open in case of errors.

Comment: The code needs a lot of cleanup. For example, the request stream seems to be opened *twice*, and one instance is stored in the top-level variable `ftpstream`. Top level variables are a *very* bad idea and the cause of a lot of bugs, because they widen the scope of values that are only needed in a very specific place. That's what happened here. In other cases they end up hiding other variables or get assigned values that were meant to be used in a specific block only

Answer (score 1):

The code contains a lot of bugs, starting from top-level variables, to converting text using what's probably the wrong codepage, to declaring streams outside using blocks.

The [How to: Upload files with FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp) page in the .NET documentation shows how to upload a file properly. The code is a lot shorter and guarantees no streams are left open.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "janeDoe@contoso.com");

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("testfile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that variables are declare in the place they're needed, not the top level. They're also assigned a value in their declaration, which ensures they'll never be null unless they're assigned a null result.

There's no need to set UseBinary, Passive and KeepAlive to true, they're enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks @panagiotis ;-) But how do I use my string xml variable in place of an existing file. Here you are using testfile.txt for example.

Comment: That's not what you asked, or what your code shows. The title says `Uploading xml file by FTP` and `s` isn't assigned anywhere. It's logical to assume it came from a file. Where *does* `s` come from? Most serializers can save directly to streams. Or you can use a [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-7.0) to write to the stream using UTF8. .NET strings are Unicode. The encoding of an XML file may be specified in the `encoding` attribute but it's almost always UTF8. XML serializers will use the correct encoding when saving to a stream